# Does Windows 10 get deleted when installing Ubuntu?

Tags: system-installation, windows

I am using Windows 10 at the moment. When installing Ubuntu, will Windows 10 get deleted? I already have prepared a bootable usb drive but I don't want to take any risks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To answer your main question first ... and take away the fears you might have ...
When you install Ubuntu properly - NO - Windows 10 will not get deleted at all !

Before you start with the Ubuntu installation you have to do some preparation :
Disable fast boot and hibernation in Windows and shutdown the PC completely.
These are necessary steps to let Ubuntu boot successfully after the installation.

Boot from Ubuntu install media and select **Try Ubuntu without installing**.
When the Live desktop appears press the Windows key and type **GParted**.

Open GParted and shrink the Windows partition when there is no free space.
Close GParted and click on Install Ubuntu, when asked select Something else.

Install Ubuntu to the unallocated space and set `/ (root)` as mount point.
Start the installation process - Ubuntu will be installed alongside Windows.
Change the default system to boot in BIOS - when UEFI based - to **Ubuntu**.

Update addressing your new information that you do not want to keep Windows :
When you want to only have Ubuntu, you can select this option from the installer.
Choose **Replace Windows with Ubuntu** - (step 4 from [Ubuntu installation guide](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/install-ubuntu-desktop)).

Comment: I would suggest resizing the Windows partitions using tools inside of windows.  A couple of years ago I broke my XP install when I resized the windows partition with gparted.

Comment: @OrganicMarble : Thank you for your contribution ! Sure, it can be done in Windows as well, but it is recommended to work on drives while being offline. As you say the issues you experienced happened a long time ago, many fixes and improvements were implemented since then. I am using GParted for years exclusively for disk operations and it never let me down, everything went smoothly without any problems.

Comment: Thank you for the responses but i WANT windows to get deleted.I don't want to install it alongside windows.

Comment: If you want to replace Windows and are not very experienced, you can just select the automatic "replace Windows and install Ubuntu" (or however it's called) option instead of "Something else" in the installer.

Comment: @ByteCommander : I implemented your contribution into the answer - thank you ! :)